# Where should I put this enum?

Tags: c++, enums

Here is my situation:

C sends an A.message to mediator B then B passes it on to A.

So essentially, C absolutely does not even need to know anything about A. The problem is it needs to know what messages it can send which is defined in an enum inside of A. This means C needs to $include A to know about the enum.

Shoving the enum globally is not something I want to do. Is the way I have it acceptable or is there a better place to put the enum so that C does not include A?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the enum in a separate file, say D, and in both C and A `#include D`